# Set 2 buttons position in all densities

Tags: android, xml, uibutton

I have to buttons, one for calculate(in the LEFT) and the other(in the RIGHT) for reset EditTexts values!
In fact i maked this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:text="Calculer" 
    android:id="@+id/button" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>
<Button
    android:text="Reset" 
    android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="280px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
 </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the reset button doesn't change in function of the screen size if the dpi is high the reset button don't take left position(almost)!
What can i solve the problem?
Thakns :).

Comment: @Konstantin Burov: i accepted the answers that really help! 2 of 9?!?! bullshit ! :(

Comment: did you found solution for the questions without useful answers? Then answer them yourself and accept those answers. You have to contribute to the community to get something back.

Comment: @Konstantin Burov: but have i to accept answers that they don't solve the problem ? anyway, i'll make an accept even if an answer is useful :)!

Comment: you don't have to accept non-useful answers. Just provide your own answers (and accept those) if you have figured out a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 280px

Don't ever use pixels in android. Use dip(density-independent-pixels) for your views.

Also, why do you use marginLeft? Use marginRight to tell android to put your button to the right margin.

Comment: Can you please post how attribute can add to a button to have it well displayed in all densities ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the android_layout_marginLeft of the Reset button to not use px. Use dp instead. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more examples.

Comment: This guide have not some XML code (attribute to add in a button) to have a support of UI elements(buttons in my case) in all densities! :(